# Someone else thinks that the UI/UX of PowerBI is horrible?

Tags: powerbi

I dont know if im the only one that thinks that there are a lot of things to improve

best organization in the menu, more flexible options, sometimes I get really stucked just finding something, and I trully think that these thibgs can be much better.

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to give feedback, use this comunity forum to get more specialized answer regarding this topic.
https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Community-Feedback/bd-p/community-feedback